# Remove grey zero reference line in R lattice barchart

Tags: r, lattice

How can one remove or change the colour of the grey zero reference line that automatically appears in an R lattice barchart when `origin = 0` is used?

Example:

```
require(lattice)

data <- data.frame(val = 1:2, id = c(-1, 1))

barchart(val ~ id, data, origin = 0)
```

I tried `zero.line = F` but couldn't get it to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the parameter `reference` to the barchart after `origin = 0`. And set it to `FALSE`.

The code looks like this:

```
require(lattice)

data <- data.frame(val = 1:2, id = c(-1, 1))

barchart(val ~ id, data, origin = 0, reference = FALSE)
```

Output:
[image]

To change the color of the reference line, you'll need to dig the parameters inside `trellis.par.get()`.
Here you'll find myriad parameters related to your graph which will change the look of it as you wish.

In your case though, just to change the color of the reference line, the required parameter is `reference.line$col`.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
reference.line <- trellis.par.get("reference.line")
reference.line$col <- "red"
trellis.par.set("reference.line", reference.line)
```

Here's the output:
[image]

The documentation for the trellis can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/lattice.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! What about changing the colour of the reference line? I know I can use `panel.abline()` to add a line of the desired type and colour, but can the original reference line be modified directly? I did try adding the abline without first removing the reference line but that did not work because the reference line was apparently drawn over the abline.

Comment: @LinYangchen, you need to tweak the parameters inside `trellis.par.get()`. Here you can change the colors of almost anything that you see in the lattice plot. In your case though, to change the reference line color, the parameter you need to tweak is `reference.line$col`